# href and ng-click do not work in the same tag on Mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href, angularjs-ng-click

href and ng-click are not both called if used in the same or overlapping tags in Mobile but work perfectly on the desktop. My guess is `touch` is what is breaking this.

Example:

```
<a href="/" ng-click="playSound()"> link </a>
```

-or-

```
<div ng-click="playSound()">
  <a href="/"> link </a>
</div>
```

Both href and ng-click are called in Desktop views but only called `playSound()` using mobile's touch.

**What I want to achieve:** I want to be able to link to the next page and also call the playSound() function on touch. Currently, ng-click overrides href on touch and I am never linked to the next page.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @VaibhavShah I want to be able to link to the next page and also call the playSound() function on touch. Currently, ng-click overrides href on touch and I am never linked to the next page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wf8a3mvh/ It works by default - check if you don't do e.preventDefault() inside playSound()

Comment: It doesn't work by default due to a bug in ngTouch: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue and found the answer [here](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/anchor-tag-isn-t-working-with-ng-touch).

In a nutshell, you can have multiple directives with the same name and both will get run when they are called. this  allows you to write a custom directive, also called `ng-click`, which requires less work than going through all of your links and moving the redirect to the function called by `ng-click`.

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('ngClick', function( $location ) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if(attrs.href) {
        elem.on('touchend', function() {
          $location.path(attrs.href);        
        });
      }
    },
    priority: 1
  };
});
```

For me, it was simple enough to move the redirect into my function and redirect the page using `$location`:

```
$location.path('www.my-link.com');
```

Comment: Just one point. I had top remove the leading `#` from the url, as it was stopping the `$location.path` from working correctly.